# C code in Android JNI - Where does the printf() output go?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface, printf

I'm porting a C code App into Android and I'm using the Java Native Interface to mix C and Java code.

I got the following code that compiles and runs without problems.

I would like to know where the `printf()` output goes because I can't find it:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int a, int b);

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring

JNICALL Java_com_example_first_1c_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv *env, jobject /* this */)
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    std::string hello = "Hello from C++";

    a = 10;
    b = 20;
    c = sum(a, b);

    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}

int sum(int a, int b)
{
    int sum;

    sum = a + b;

    printf("Sum = %d", sum);

    return sum;
};
```

Comment: Don't use `printf`. Use Android's [logging functions](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/logging) instead (e.g. `__android_log_print`).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I can't do that. I can't modify the C source code.

Comment: You don’t have any choice. You have to modify it.

Answer (score 2):

`printf()` uses `stdout` for the output, which is something JNI can change.  This `FILE *` descriptor normally is associated with UNIX file descriptor 1, so it depends on how have you started the program.  It's quite common that unix applications that don't redirect standard output to some specific location get that output lost (being mainly because they are redirected output to `/dev/null`)

Are you starting the java program from a linux console? are you starting it from some script?  The inspection on how the java virtual mathine has been started, will tell you where the standard output goes.  As Java in linux uses `System.out` to direct its output, it is quite probably that you won't be able to use `stdio` package functions inside your JNI module.

Anyway, stdio is a module that buffers it's output, if you just call `printf()`, just ensute to call `fflush(stdout);` after your call, to enforce the writing of the buffer to the output channel, or `setbuf(stdout, NULL);` before using `printf()`.   This will ensure that `printf()` flushes the buffer at each call, and you get your output somewhere.  Most probably your output is not shown because it's still in the buffer.  I recommend you to do, at least the following:

```
int sum(int a, int b)
{
    int sum;

    sum = a + b;

    printf("Sum = %d\n", sum);
    fflush(stdout);

    return sum;
} // ;  /* <-- never end a function body with a semicolon */
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer that somewhat helped me understand the scenario. Do you know if C and Java code are executed in 2 different processes?